# Error while adding Firebase to Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-beta1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-41
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:44 to override.

Comment: Edit version `com.android.support:appcompat` and `com.android.support:support` same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to fix the version mentioned in your gradle file.
All of the dependencies should have same version number.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is already provided in ur error... 
just goto ur manifest, inside application tag put this : `tools:replace="android:value"`

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: if it is not solving by above method then try to make all versions of the libraries same... in app level gradle... if 12.0.4 then all firebase libraries should be of 12.0.4

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit version `com.android.support:appcompat:26.1.0` and `com.android.support:support:26.1.0` same.
2. Add this line into manifest:

`<application 
...
...
tools:replace="android:value">`

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs